# Host File method not working on HostGator site

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, hostgator

I am transferring a WP site to a HostGator shared server account. I have everything set up but want to test the site before I propagate the domain name. To do this I want to alter my Host File to point to the new server, eg:

```
108.167.111.11 mysite.com
108.167.111.11 www.mysite.com
```

I've done this dozens of times before, but this time it's not working.

I get a 404 page with the HostGator logo, so that encouraging - its getting to the right host - but not site content as expected.

Would anyone know if there is a special way to do this with HostGator?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the IP address that came with my HostGator account information email was not the right one. I logged into CPanel via the temporary URL and found the actual IP address listed on the column to the right towards the bottom.

[image]

Comment: "...was not the right one" - was it wrong initially? Or had it changed?

Comment: @w3d Im guessing it was wrong initially since the account is only about a week old.

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy tool on many computers that you can use to find an IP address of a domain.

Just open up a command prompt and type:

```
ping www.mysite.com
```

or type:

```
ping mysite.com
```

Then you'll see the IP the site is connected to. For example, to find out google's IP, type:

```
ping google.com
```

and you'll get results that begin like this:

```
PING google.ca (74.125.226.159) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Then once every second, you'll receive the following line with slightly different numbers after the time:

```
64 bytes from yyz08s14-in-f31.1e100.net (74.125.226.159): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=8.37 ms
```

If I'm not mistaken, the above line appears four times in windows then the program exits. I use linux so I have to use CTRL+C to exit ping. Once ping ends, I see the following:

```
--- google.ca ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.181/8.535/8.962/0.295 ms
```

Next, to verify the information is correct, copy the IP address in brackets and use it in your browser. In this case, the IP is 74.125.226.159
I typed it in, and it is google.